# Upgrade msbuild project target framework to .net6

Tags: .net, sdk, rider, .net-4.8

I want to upgrade my project from .net 4.8 to .net 6.0, as picture below shows, it's using msbuild to build project (unlike sdk-styled projects)

[image]

When i change TargetFrameworkVersion to v6.0, it shows an error saying that cannot find .netframework v.6 while it's already installed on my machine and other projects are already using it.

[image]

Now I'm confused why MSbuild cannot detect my .net6 sdk?
I also tried to upgrade msbuild version to 17, but didn't work.

Other project is using .net6 without any issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Projects targeting .Net Framework versions are not directly convertable to projects using Core versions such as .Net 6.

Conversion of a project built on the framework (regardless the version, till 4.8) might take a little bit more than just adjusting target framework for build. It might require Nuget package reference adjustments with follow up C# configuration for the runtime and library adjustments as some features in some core libraries might be using different types, or might throw runtime or build errors for few things that are obsolete or redundant in .net core in general, or should be used or configured otherwise

If there's any mapping between these objects to local entities, those need to be adjusted as well.

So for any application, you have to consider these things to migrate .Net framework version to .Net Core version